# Cookies deep subdomains

Tags: cookies

Looking for some input on cookies and subdomain, I have already read [1][2] and [3].

If I set a cookie's domain to ".live.example.com"

Will the cookie be available to api.live.example.com?

I believe the answer is Yes.

Will the cookie be available to uat.example.com?

I believe the answer is No.

Additional Cookie Attributes will be set, these should be irrelevant, but I will mention in case someone sees them as relevant:

httpOnly - enabled

Secure - enabled

Expires - end of session

Under what conditions would the cookie not be sent to api.live.example.com (site has a valid SSL certificate, relevant if someone suggests site not in SSL mode as secure flag is set)?

Why do I ask this second question?

I have previously set a cookie to ".example.com". The cookie did not send to api.example.com via XMLHTTPRequest (js loaded from [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)), but opening another browser tab and doing a GET request to api.example.com the cookie is sent. Therefore, browser is making some decision here.

Have I read anything already?

Yes, I have reviewed the following question on stackoverflow, and also read RFC6265 sections 5.1.3 and 5.2.3. Nothing I have read suggests the approach will not work:

[1] Existing stackoverflow question - Cookies Subdomains
[Share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain)

[2] RFC State Management - Domain Matching
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.3

[3] RFC State Management - Domain Attribute
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.3

Comment: _“The cookie did not send to api.example.com via XMLHTTPRequest”_ - then you likely did not specify the request attribute necessary to send credentials such as cookies with cross-domain requests ...

Comment: _"then you likely did not specify the request attribute necessary to send credentials"_ Can you be more specific please?

Comment: @CBroe are you referring to : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

Comment: Yes, I am. You need to explicitly specify that you want to send such credentials with a cross-domain request.

Comment: @CBroe - thank you - Yes this was missing. I will confirm.

Comment: @CBroe just tested and yes this fixed the question regarding: _“The cookie did not send to api.example.com via XMLHTTPRequest”_

Comment: Regarding your first two Yes/No questions, you’re correct on those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm I have created a test case to answer these questions:

> Will the cookie be available to api.live.example.com?

The Answer is YES.

> Will the cookie be available to uat.example.com?

The Answer is NO.

As noted by @CBroe, for XMLHTTPRequests, the withCredentials flag must be set to true [1].

And, in case anyone asks the question what about "www.example.com"

> Will the cookie be available to www.example.com?

Hopefully, it is obvious from the previous question / answer.

No, the cookie will not be available to www.example.com

[1] XMLHTTPRequest withCredentials.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials